# Cannot setup a drupal webform to work with GoCardless and CiviCRM contribution

Tags: civicontribute, webform-civicrm, gocardless

I'm trying to setup a contribution page so that users can choose gocardless or paypal as a recurring donation option. This seems to work when using the form built into the CiviCRM Contribution system. Whenever I try and do this using the webform function (which would be much preferred in terms of the flexibility over the look/branding etc) I am unable to setup a payment using the GoCardless sandbox. My site will happily send me to the GoCardless sandbox, and let me fill in details, but when returning to my site I get sent to the CiviCRM contribution page with the message

"Your browser session has expired and we are unable to complete your form submission. We have returned you to the initial step so you can complete and resubmit the form. If you experience continued difficulties, please contact us for assistance."

Is this a known bug? Has anyone else encountered this?

Thanks for any help

Edited to add - we're on CiviCRM  5.58.1 and Drupal 9.5.7

Comment: Andrew - we had this working a couple of years back. You may need to update the question with what version of things you are using. The issue, at the time. was related to stripe extension js.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, I've edited to add that info. I hadn't thought to try Stripe, thanks for the suggestion. If it works for us it would solve a headache.

Comment: In hindsight i am not too sure what was the impact of stripe - but perhaps you can disable stripe and retest?

Comment: we may have had a fix on that site for this but has been a long time since we had to do anything for them. i will see if the guy who worked in it can take a quick look or has a better memory than me

Comment: Ah ok thanks. Just to be clear: so far we haven't made GoCardless work via webform, so testing with Stripe instead. I've setup an account and got everything set up, but Stripe asked me for a "return_url" for the paymentintent confirmation, which I think is beyond my tech skills because I can't work out how to do it from the interface, so I'll get the company that does our development work on it. Thanks for the help.